# Stop a process when my PC sleeps

Tags: suspend

I would like to start/stop a process before my PC sleeps or wakes up.

I don't know how to do that.

The command is:

Before sleep: `killall libinput-debug-events`
After wakeup: `libinput-gestures-setup start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1 - using a script within `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` directory

Create a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    killall libinput-debug-events
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    libinput-gestures-setup start
    ;;
esac
```

To ensure the script is created with the right permissions, copy and existing script and then edit it:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system-sleep
sudo cp wpasupplicant tv_refresh
gksu gedit tv_refresh
```

The `sleep 2` pause may be unnecessary for you but for my setup it was necessary restoring sound from laptop back to HDMI TV.

The `echo` lines are optional but are handy because they show up in `/var/log/syslog`.

### Method 2 - using `systemd` services for `root` or `user`

From: ([archlinux - Power Management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management)) we get detailed instructions for suspending and resuming either under `root` powers or `user` powers.

#### Suspend/resume service files

Service files can be hooked into suspend.target, hibernate.target and sleep.target to execute actions before or after suspend/hibernate. Separate files should be created for user actions and root/system actions. Enable the suspend@user and resume@user services to have them started at boot. Examples:

#### Suspend

```
/etc/systemd/system/suspend@.service
[Unit]
Description=User suspend actions
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStartPre= -/usr/bin/pkill -u %u unison ; /usr/local/bin/music.sh stop ; /usr/bin/mysql -e 'slave stop'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sflock
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

#### Resume

```
/etc/systemd/system/resume@.service
[Unit]
Description=User resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/ssh-connect.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysql -e 'slave start'

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tryied this solution.
The problem is maybe these command are execute by root, for the killall command I think it's not a problem, but for libinput-gestures-setup start this one must be exec by me, not by root>

Comment: Currently I try to use : "    sudo -u user libinput-gestures-setup start", works in my term but not in the script, I will look at syslog

Comment: I was using kill command yesterday and it doesn't need sudo. If killall needs sudo try putting that in front.

Comment: I didn't undestand your comment.
The problem was not about killall command, and not about sudo permission.
I just need to run "libinput-gestures-setup start" as a simple user, I tryied several way but without succes.
I cannot see anything in syslog file, no error.
How to run a cmd with my personnal account, not with root ?
Currently I tried : sudo su - user -c "libinput-gestures-setup start", work in terminal, but not on system-sleep script

Comment: When you suspend and resume using the above script do you see the lines: "Going to sleep" and "Waking from sleep" in syslog? Any errors after that?

Comment: Yes I see these lines, but no error after that.

Comment: I'm on my phone but I'll experiment with your code tonight. If it can't be made to work in systemd then another approach is needed.

Comment: @Shining Sorry this took so long but I wasn't sure the best route to take. I've added method 2 which I feel is best for you based on your comments. Normally I like to setup on my own system first but I don't have any applications to kill or start up on suspend/resume with user only powers. I anticipate you might have additional comments and I will be more than happy to update the answer. Thanks for waiting.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I didn't undestand anything, I red your post and ArchWiki (sorry I'm not english)
So I think I will continue with a manual launch after each wake up (little bit boring but work).

Comment: After you gain more experience you can always search for your question again and try it.

Comment: I think I will ask for help from French Users (who has experience) to try this solution. This problem is not so big, so ... no problem. Thank you a lot for your help, I can stop my service before sleep and that was the biggest problem (no touchpad at wakeup if the service is running ! I always must reboot).
Have a nice day and thank you again !